# Collections on watson discovery not being created and showing API timeout issue

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-discovery

Each time we look to create a collection on the discovery GUI using the API we are getting API timeout issues. This happens very erratically.

Answer (score 0):

IBM provides one Website to see if the Services and Systems work fine. The site shows if have Maintenance and the Problems with the services.
I had the same problem with another service. My service works fine now. Verify if you service are ok and check if the service was with status `no known issues` too.

**Check the error:**

[image]

See the [Website](https://status.ng.bluemix.net/).